# Octobercms Upload Files

Tags: php, file-upload, model, components, octobercms

How to solve the error?

[image]

this is my htm code (button upload)

```
{{ form_open({files: true, request: 'onFileUpload'}) }}

<!--File Input-->
<input type="file" name="file-upload" required="required">
<!--File Input-->

<!--Submit/Upload Button-->
<button type="submit">Upload</button>

{{ form_close() }}
```

this is the component php code

```
     public function onFileUpload()
{
    $file = new System\Models\File;
    $file->data = Input::file('file-upload');
    $file->save();

    // Attach the uploaded file to your model
    $model->file()->add($file); 
   // The above line assumes you have proper attachOne or attachMany relationships defined on your model

    $model->file_path = url('/') . $model->file->getPath();
    $model->save();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

is this the proper attachMany relationship?

```
public $attachMany = [
'files' => 'System\Models\File',
];
}
```

I'm not very sure about the code cause I'm new to October cms
Can anyone show some examples?
How to create a drag and drop file uploader component?

Comment: Just like the error says: you are trying to add something to $model->file(), but variable $model was never initiated. So $model is nothing at that point.

Comment: I added this $model = new Uploadedfile;(<<< model) but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to new up an instance of the model that you've defined you relationship in and set it as your $model variable.

For example.. your model class could look like this.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public attachMany [
        'files' => 'System\Models\File'
    ];
}
```

And then in your component onFileUpload()

```
$model = new User;
$model->files()->add($file); 
$model->file_path = url('/') . $model->file->getPath();
$model->save();
```

Also, just take notice that your attachMany relationship in your model class is defined as files but you're trying to use it with

```
$model->file()->add();
```

It should be

```
$model->files()->add();
```